# ¿No han notado que la documentacion en español no es buena?

Tags: discusión

Puede existir una sección de stackoverflow dedicado para la habla hispana, pero cuando se trata de buscar como implementar una librería o alguna funcionalidad, la mayoría por no decir todos, los más completos son los que están en inglés.
No les parece?

Comment: Buenas Luis. ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Sugieres algo al respecto?  Un saludo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que hace rico en conocimientos a StackOverflow es la gran cantidad de preguntas y respuestas que tiene. A día de hoy tiene más de 17 millones de preguntas y respuestas, acumuladas a lo largo de más de 10 años. StackOverflow en español tiene algo más de 81.000 preguntas acumuladas en algo más de 3 años. Además del tiempo, el número de usuarios de uno u otro es completamente diferente: SOes apenas tiene 1300 usuarios con una reputación de más de 100, mientras que SO tiene casi medio millón.

La única manera de aumentar y mejorar el conocimiento acumulado de la versión en español es mediante los usuarios: necesitamos usuarios activos que pregunten y respondan dudas. Esto requiere un esfuerzo, por supuesto: cada vez que no encuentres una respuesta en español pero sí en inglés, podrías crear esa pregunta y auto-responderla, ya sea traduciendo la respuesta original o aportando los conocimientos aprendidos desde cualquier otra fuente.

También puedes sencillamente preguntar y/o responder preguntas de otros usuarios para que entre todos vayamos añadiendo lo que sabemos.

Para bien o para mal, es el único camino.

Comment: Es cierto. Es el unico camino, creo que debemos aportar muchas más ideas y soluciones, no simplemente buscar, encontrar y resolver el problema que uno tenga. No creo que sea fácil, pero crear esa cultura entre tantos usuarios a nivel muncial es lo que mejoría esta Sección SO.